# Covariance Pattern for Abstract Classes

Tags: c#

I'm realizing now that covariance is not available in abstract classes but is there anyway that I can utilize it here so that I can continue with this pattern.

Basically want the ability to create an instance of the first generic argument and pass the object which creates this object itself.

The below will fail at runtime because SpecialProcessor cannot be assigned to ProcessorBase with respect to generic types.

Appreciate any suggestions.

```
public class ProcessorUser<T> where T : ProcessorBase
{
    public void ReceiveCommand()
    {
        Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), this);
    }
}

public abstract class ProcessorBase
{
    protected ProcessorBase(ProcessorUser<ProcessorBase> param)
    {
    }
}

public class SpecialProcessor : ProcessorBase
{
    public SpecialProcessor(ProcessorUser<ProcessorBase> param)
        : base(param)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, from your less-than-complete code example, it's not clear at all a) what you are trying to do, and b) what "fails at runtime". You didn't show any code that calls the `ReceiveCommand()` method, so it's impossible to see in what way that code might fail.

That said, the usual way to gain access to variance in C# is through delegate or interface types. So you can declare a covariant interface to be implemented by `ProcessorUser<T>`, and then use that interface in the constructor declarations instead of the actual type. For example:

```
interface IProcessorUser<out T> where T : ProcessorBase
{
    void ReceiveCommand();
}

class ProcessorUser<T> : IProcessorUser<T> where T : ProcessorBase
{
    public void ReceiveCommand()
    {
        Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), this);
    }
}

abstract class ProcessorBase
{
    protected ProcessorBase(IProcessorUser<ProcessorBase> param)
    {
    }
}

class SpecialProcessor : ProcessorBase
{
    private IProcessorUser<SpecialProcessor> _param;

    public SpecialProcessor(IProcessorUser<SpecialProcessor> param)
        : base(param)
    {
        _param = param;
    }

    public void ReceiveCommand() { _param.ReceiveCommand(); }
}
```

Note that I added the `ReceiveCommand()` method to the `SpecialProcessor` class just so I could see *something* execute at run-time. And that something does in fact work. But there's no way for me to know whether in your scenario, this is what you wanted to happen. You'd have to provide [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows what you are trying to do and what difficulty you are having doing it, if you want a clear, precise answer to that aspect of it.

(By the way, this really doesn't have anything to do with `abstract` classes. There's not even anything in your code example that is actually `abstract`, other than the class declaration itself, and the general principle applies to any class, not just `abstract` ones).

Comment: For a question that apparently is not clear enough you provide a working answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @Dave: glad to be able to help. I took a guess...happy to hear it was on the mark enough to help! :)

Comment: I think the take home here is that if any sort of reference must be made back to the calling class.  The class itself MUST implement a co variant interface.  Note the calling class in my case inherited from a fairly large class.  So I added this class as a property to the interface itself.